# Diferencias entre tipos de funciones en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, c#, asp.net

Buenas tardes Comunidad.

Como lo indico en el titulo de la pregunta, veo que en las aplicaciones que estamos programando en mi lugar de trabajo, se usan estos dos tipos de funciones.

scope.NombreDeLaFuncion = function(){
}

y

function NombreDeLaFuncion(){
}

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Podrían ayudarme indicándome cual es la diferencia entre estas, y algún ejemplo de caso de uso?

He Googleado los conceptos pero no he encontrado algún sitio que haga referencia a la función que usa scope y la diferencia entre funcion().

Buen fin de semana.

Comment: Puedes consultar [la documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions#defining_functions) si quieres indagar.

Comment: Cuando es function NombreDeLaFuncion(){ } la función es de caracter global, si ya existe otra con ese nombre; se remplaza, se puede llamar desde cualquier script. 
En cambio scope.NombreDeLaFuncion = function(){ }, esta dentro de un objeto llamado $scope, tu puedes crear tantos objetos como quieras así puedes tener una función llamada saludar() en el $objeto1 y otra saludar() en el $objeto2 y no se remplaza una por la otra, ya que cada una pertenece a un objeto diferente.